# Swift 3 google map add markers on touch

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I got problem with google map markers, I want to put marker on touch but I don't know how to handle it I tried a few way but it's not working, nothing happens then I touch on map. It seems something wrong with pressrecognizer.

**Updated:**

```
class MainMapController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
var makers: [GMSMarker] = []

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    initializeTheLocationManager()
    self.viewMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
  let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
  self.viewMap.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)


}

  func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
   {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began)
{
  let longPressPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.viewMap);
  let coordinate = viewMap.projection.coordinate(for: longPressPoint )
  let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
  marker.opacity = 0.6
  marker.title = "Current Location"
  marker.snippet = ""
  marker.map = viewMap
  makers.append(marker)
    }
  }


func initializeTheLocationManager()
{
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,      didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    var location = locationManager.location?.coordinate

    cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: location)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()     
}    
func cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
    if toLocation != nil {
        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: toLocation!, zoom: 15)        
    }
    }
```

Comment: viewMap is an GMSMapView ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: I tried and nothing happens when I tapped on map

Comment: Can you show me more code ?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @EgleMatutyte you get the solution?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't add gesture recognisers manually for Google Maps, it manages it's interactions itself and has dedicated delegate functions to handle common gestures.

To do a long press on a GSMMapView ensure that you set the delegate

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

and then wire up the appropriate delegate function

```
extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
         // Custom logic here
         let marker = GMSMarker()
         marker.position = coordinate
         marker.title = "I added this with a long tap"
         marker.snippet = ""
         marker.map = mapView
    }
}
```

The code above will add a marker at the location you long pressed at, you can also add a title and snippet as you can see. the part that actually adds it to the map is `marker.map = mapView`

Comment: I tried to add this, but when I tapp on map nothing happens.

Comment: you doing a long tap? I have a sample project here with this code in and it works fine for me

Comment: Yes I am, and nothing happen, could you show me it?

Comment: See this git repository. remember to add your API_KEY to AppDelegate to run. https://github.com/martinjkelly/gmaps-ios-long-tap-sample