# Swift 5: How to add Marker on GoogleMap on tap/touch with coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

*I was learning GoogleMap-SDK for iOS, in the process i did searched for the above question and found satisfactory answers but not the one that's practically useful.*

E.G. : [Swift 3 google map add markers on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877300/swift-3-google-map-add-markers-on-touch/43879138)

It adds Marker but does not have Place Name or Place Details and without that Marker is not that useful and for that i have to search other answers to get Address from the coordinates.

So , here i have combined both answers to save time of fellow developers and make it Marker more practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Swift 5.0+**

> First, make sure you have added `GMSMapViewDelegate` delegate to your ViewController Class

We do not need `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer` for this, `GMSMapViewDelegate` provides convenient default method for this.

```
///This default function fetches the coordinates on long-press on `GoogleMapView`
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
     
     //Creating Marker
     let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    
     let decoder = CLGeocoder()

     //This method is used to get location details from coordinates
     decoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)) { placemarks, err in
        if let placeMark = placemarks?.first {

            let placeName = placeMark.name ?? placeMark.subThoroughfare ?? placeMark.thoroughfare!   ///Title of Marker
            //Formatting for Marker Snippet/Subtitle       
            var address : String! = ""
            if let subLocality = placeMark.subLocality ?? placeMark.name {
                address.append(subLocality)
                address.append(", ")
            }
            if let city = placeMark.locality ?? placeMark.subAdministrativeArea {
                address.append(city)
                address.append(", ")
            }
            if let state = placeMark.administrativeArea, let country = placeMark.country {
                address.append(state)
                address.append(", ")
                address.append(country)
            }

            // Adding Marker Details
            marker.title = placeName
            marker.snippet = address
            marker.appearAnimation = .pop
            marker.map = mapView
        }
    }
}
```

***HOPE IT HELPS !!!***

Comment: Please note that [CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation) calls are rate limited by iOS and may fail inconsistently. As long as you are using Google Maps, you should consider using [GMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder#a9b50eaa9e72ec615b5732bedd03c600c)

Comment: @TarunTyagi, thanks for suggestion..after your comment i did try `GMSGeocoder` to fetch location address and I compared both the results....and conclusion is that Apple's CLGeocoder is much more precise in getting the place-name while GMSGeocoder does not fetch place-name accurately.